# Order by on Entity Framework Load

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I would like to add an orderby when I call `Load()` in the following example:

(Note:  This object has an EF Article that has been loaded somewhere else)

```
    private string GetTags()
    {
        var tags = this.Article.tags;
        if (!tags.IsLoaded && this.Article.EntityState != EntityState.Detached)
        {
            tags.Load();
            tags.OrderBy(t => t.name);
        }

        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var tag in tags)
        {
            result.Append(tag.name).Append(" ");
        }
        return result.ToString();
    }
```

The problem is this is not sorting the tags in alphebetical order.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like most other LINQ methods, `OrderBy` doesn't affect the underlying query, which is immutable. You have to do something with the value it returns:

```
this.Article.tags = tags.OrderBy(t => t.name);
```

The problem is, `tags` is not an IEnumerable or IQueryable: it is an EntityCollection. So the above statement won't work very well. Furthermore, your method name (`GetTags`) doesn't very well indicate that you're going to be modifying the order of the tags on the `Article` object, so it might be better to just keep the `OrderBy` local, and do it again each time someone calls `GetTags`:

```
    var tags = this.Article.tags;
    if (!tags.IsLoaded && this.Article.EntityState != EntityState.Detached)
    {
        tags.Load();
    }

    return string.Join(" ", tags.Select(t => t.name).OrderBy(t => t))
```

Comment: Can I orderby when I do the `this.Article.tags.Load()`?

Comment: @DMoses: There are some tricks you can do to get this to work properly when eager loading (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/02/25/tip-1-sorting-relationships-in-entity-framework.aspx), but I don't know of any way to apply an `OrderBy` to lazy loading like that. Of course, you could just perform a separate query to get the tags that are tied to the article you're on, and order them as part of your query, but that won't automatically load them onto the `Article.tags` property.

Answer (score 3):

You've not assigned tags.OrderBy() to anything, set it to another variable and iterate over that, e.g.

```
var orderedTags = tags.OrderBy(t => t.name)
...
foreach(var tag in orderedTags) {
....
}
```